# Can using a constant global variable stop the issue of 'side effects' completely?

Tags: oop, global-variables, side-effects

I am aware that the purpose of Functional Programming (FP) is to disallow 'side effects', that traditionally appear in object-oriented, imperative languages due to the use of global variables (for example).

However, in OOP (Non-FP) languages, can 'side effects' disappear if one uses a global variable that is constant (so it's value will never change)?

Comment: The side effects associated with that global variable might do, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "global variable" but seem like the answer is No.

What is more important is whether variables are mutable or immutable. That means that if you send some class to function you can be sure that is not changed.

Now it also depends on what is "side effects" - which have nothing to do with mutability. e.g you can send an imutable instance to method, you are not going to change the instant but you are going to do some other operation like adding/deleting records base on that instance or create/delete files on the FS

Comment: By 'global variable', I mean a variable that has global scope, that is accessible throughout the program; many functions would have access to this variable.

Comment: @mts396 like I said in my answer, I don't think this is the right question since global variable are at most a single example for side effect